# MySQL Group by not produce as expected

Tags: mysql, group-by, count

I have several rows of records that need to count (how many transactions) for each month. Then came up with below query which count txn for each months

output:

[image: count result for each month]

I try to make single line output. but when I group by uid, it will sum and put in JAN2023 column (which is incorrect):

[image: group by uid]

```
SELECT 
(IF(payment.paymentMonth='01', COUNT(payment.paymentId), 0)) as JAN2023,
(IF(payment.paymentMonth='02', COUNT(payment.paymentId), 0)) as FEB2023,
(IF(payment.paymentMonth='03', COUNT(payment.paymentId), 0)) as MAC2023,
(IF(payment.paymentMonth='04', COUNT(payment.paymentId), 0)) as APR2023,
(IF(payment.paymentMonth='05', COUNT(payment.paymentId), 0)) as MAY2023,
(IF(payment.paymentMonth='06', COUNT(payment.paymentId), 0)) as JUN2023,
(IF(payment.paymentMonth='07', COUNT(payment.paymentId), 0)) as JUL2023,
(IF(payment.paymentMonth='08', COUNT(payment.paymentId), 0)) as AUG2023,
(IF(payment.paymentMonth='09', COUNT(payment.paymentId), 0)) as SEP2023,
(IF(payment.paymentMonth='10', COUNT(payment.paymentId), 0)) as OCT2023,
(IF(payment.paymentMonth='11', COUNT(payment.paymentId), 0)) as NOV2023,
(IF(payment.paymentMonth='12', COUNT(payment.paymentId), 0)) as DEC2023,
bill.uid as uid,
payment.paymentYear as paymentYear
FROM payment
JOIN bill ON bill.billId = payment.paymentBillId
AND paymentYear='2023'
AND (paymentSubChannel='epay' OR paymentSubChannel='gpay' OR paymentSubChannel='tpay' OR paymentSubChannel='bpay')
AND payment.paymentStatus = 1
AND bill.uid = 51
GROUP BY payment.paymentMonth
```

Comment: See [Tips for asking a good Structured Query Language (SQL) question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/271055), #5 and #3. Also read [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to place the conditional logic inside the aggregate function. Typically this uses **case expressions** as seen below.

```
SELECT
      COUNT(CASE WHEN payment.paymentMonth = '01' THEN 1 END) AS JAN2023
    , COUNT(CASE WHEN payment.paymentMonth = '02' THEN 1 END) AS FEB2023
    , COUNT(CASE WHEN payment.paymentMonth = '03' THEN 1 END) AS MAR2023
    , COUNT(CASE WHEN payment.paymentMonth = '04' THEN 1 END) AS APR2023
    , COUNT(CASE WHEN payment.paymentMonth = '05' THEN 1 END) AS MAY2023
    , COUNT(CASE WHEN payment.paymentMonth = '06' THEN 1 END) AS JUN2023
    , COUNT(CASE WHEN payment.paymentMonth = '07' THEN 1 END) AS JUL2023
    , COUNT(CASE WHEN payment.paymentMonth = '08' THEN 1 END) AS AUG2023
    , COUNT(CASE WHEN payment.paymentMonth = '09' THEN 1 END) AS SEP2023
    , COUNT(CASE WHEN payment.paymentMonth = '10' THEN 1 END) AS OCT2023
    , COUNT(CASE WHEN payment.paymentMonth = '11' THEN 1 END) AS NOV2023
    , COUNT(CASE WHEN payment.paymentMonth = '12' THEN 1 END) AS DEC2023
    , bill.uid as uid
    , payment.paymentYear AS paymentYear
FROM payment
JOIN bill ON bill.billId = payment.paymentBillId
WHERE paymentYear = '2023'
    AND (
           paymentSubChannel = 'epay'
        OR paymentSubChannel = 'gpay'
        OR paymentSubChannel = 'tpay'
        OR paymentSubChannel = 'bpay'
        )
    AND payment.paymentStatus = 1
    AND bill.uid = 51
GROUP BY
      paymentYear
    , bill.uid
```

Remember that the case expression simply decides if there is 1 or null for a specific month, then those 1's are counted by the aggregation. The technique is called "conditional aggregation" i.e. condition first, then aggregate

Comment: Thank you for the answer and short explanation on conditional aggregation. This answer helps me produce result as expected and hope will help others. TQ